# Permutations and group acts

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ordered pairs of permutations $(\pi , \sigma )$ in $S_n$ such that $\pi \circ \sigma =\sigma \circ \pi $.

I think i need consider group acts on itself by conjugation $\pi (\sigma )=\pi \circ \sigma \circ \pi ^{-1}$. I need help or hint.

Comment: Solved in detail in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401234/ordered-pairs-of-permutations-in-symmetric-group .

Answer (score 3):

Hints: (1) the number of permutations commuting with a given one depend only on the conjugacy class of the latter (2) for any finite group acting on a finite set (here you can take $S_n$ acting on itself by conjugation) the number of orbits equals the *average* number (over the group) of fixed points. Come to think of it, just hint (2) should do the trick.

Comment: I solved it. Thank you.